# A single C++ variable has conflicting values in debugger?

Tags: c++, xcode

Please see the screenshot below. I noticed some erroneous results in my code so I went to debug.

As you can see, I put a break point when the variable 'latest' is equal to "5". BUT, apparently the application is hitting on this break point even thought 'latest' is equal to "2", not "5". Any idea what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: You can hit that breakpoint without `latest == "5"` being true (assuming the BP is on line 87). It's checking the condition.

Comment: With proper formatting (meaning not cramming condition and conditional statement on the same line), you wouldn't have that problem. What makes you think the breakpoint is in the `{;}` statement rather than at `if (latest == "5")`?

Comment: The statement is an `if` statement.  Regardless of the value of `latest`, that statement still has to be executed, otherwise how would the test be done?

Comment: Unrelated, but the `substr()` calls are just taking the whole string, no need for them.

Comment: Horizontal scroll is one of most annoying thing when reading code.

Answer (score 2):

Format your code like this (`>>` denoting the breakpoint):

```
    if (latest == "5")
    {
>>    ;
    }
```

rather than this:

```
>>   if (latest == "5") {;}
```

In the latter case the breakpoint is at the `if`, not at the `;`  inside the `{}`.

Cramming too many statements on the same line makes step by step debugging painful and makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 2):

> I put a break point when the variable `latest` is equal to `"5"`

No, you put a breakpoint where the variable `latest` is *compared* to `"5"`. The comparison has to happen before the `if` statement knows which branch to take.

Answer (score 1):

Your code rather than this:

```
if (latest == "5") {;}
```

**Only use single-line if statements on a single line**

The problem occurs when a single-line if the statement is broken up into two lines. While the compiler sees this as one statement guarded by a single condition, humans often accidentally read this is an if block, whether there are curly braces or not, thanks to the indentation. Humans notice the indentation, the compiler does not.

```
if (latest == "5") 
     ;
```

If the statement you’re guarding is small, and not worth the extra heft of curly braces, just put it on the same line.